# The listener for function 'IotHubTrigger' was unable to start. IoTHub

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I've been working on a azure functions project for almost a year now.
Suddenly last week i started to get this error message from my IoTHubTrigger:

**The listener for function 'IotHubTrigger' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor: Out of retries creating lease for partition 0. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The response ended prematurely, with at least 158 additional bytes expected. System.Net.Http: The response ended prematurely, with at least 158 additional bytes expected.**

Have not found anywhere where someone has the same problem as this, someone who knows what the error is due to?
The only major change the last weeks is that i went from VS 2019 to VS 2022, can it be that?

Also added `"AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",` to the local.settings.json file.

I'm thankful for any kind of help with this!
Cheers!

Comment: You can refer to [Azure Functions with IoT Hub not able to retrieve partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70450552) and [Azure EventHub EventProcessorHost Storage Account issue : Out of retries creating lease for partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105730/azure-eventhub-eventprocessorhost-storage-account-issue-out-of-retries-creatin)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it did not solve my problem :/ @DeepDave-MT

Comment: I'm getting the same error for Eventhub

Comment: @byteArrayJake - Do you use a local Azure Storage emulator ("AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true") or a real Azure Storage Account for your Azure Function?

Comment: I'm using the local Azure Storage emulator e.g ("AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true") @ChristianVorhemus

Comment: @byteArrayJake After you open your VS Function project in the Output window you should see a line like "azurite.cmd --location "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Azurite" --debug "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Azurite\debug.log" - can you start the function and then share the content of debug.log?

Comment: @byteArrayJake - If the error is `listener for the function was unable to start, then could you please try these steps: 1) Run the azure storage explorer as admin 2) end the tasks 'func' and 'host process for windows tasks' from task manager and Run the function!

Comment: @ChristianVorhemus - How much of it do you need to see? I have shared a peace of it in my question!

Comment: @byteArrayJake I don't see a relevant error message in the part you posted but we see that you use Azurite v3.14.1 (the local storage emulator)  which is the version that comes with Visual Studio 2022. Azurite was not part of VS 2019 and had to be installed manually so maybe the files created by your older Azurite causes a conflict now. In the same folder where debug.log is located there should be a directory named "\_\_blobstorage\_\_" which stores the leases locally. Can you try to rename that to "\_\_blobstorage\_\_old" and re-run the function app?

Comment: @ChristianVorhemus - I did as you said, i can see that a new directory was created, but i still getting the same error message :/

Comment: @ChristianVorhemus - I can see some errors in the log now, check my question again!

Comment: @byteArrayJake, Every request made against the storage services returns a response header named x-ms-request-id. This header contains an opaque value that uniquely identifies the request.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/troubleshooting-api-operations

Comment: If a request is consistently failing and you have verified that the request is properly formulated, you may use this value to **report the error to Microsoft.** In your report, include the value of x-ms-request-id, the approximate time that the request was made, the storage service against which the request was made, and the type of operation that the request attempted.

Comment: Have you managed to solve it ? @emrekara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, in AzureStorageExplorer under local/Emulator/blobcontainer/azure-webjobs-eventhub & host, removed everything that had to do with iothub/eventhub, and did a restart on the computer and boom so it started to work again.

Thanks to the people who left a comment!